# Interaction between two tables ID-Name

Tags: php, function, output

Good morning,

I should cross two tables to make the names of the companies appear in a table.

Example:

> USER TABLE:
>  ID - USERNAME - WHATICANSEE 
>  1  | User     |
>   1,2,3
>  COMPANY TABLE:
>  ID - NAMECOMPANY
>  1  | Carrots
>   
>  2  | Apple
>  3  | Potato

"Whaticansee" contain value like "1,2,3" that are equivalent to "ID" Company table.
That's my code:

```
function TabDipendenti(){
require 'db.php';
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");
//CODE CREATE <TABLE>
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<td><a href=/az.php?id=" . $row['WHATICANSEE'] . ">". $row['WHATICANSEE'] ."</a></td>";
}
//CODE </TABLE>
}
```

So i need to output "`NAMECOMPANY`" from select by "`WHATICANSEE`" (value with multi ID).
Now the output is :

```
1 - User - 1,2,3
```

but the right process is:

```
1 - User - Carrots,Apple,Potato
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You should create an associative table (`EMPLOYEE`?) with 2 fields: `USER_ID`, `COMPANY_ID`.
Then you juste have to query: `SELECT u.USERNAME, c.NAMECOMPANY FROM USER u INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON e.USER_ID = u.ID INNER JOIN COMPANY ON e.COMPANY_ID = c.ID`

Can you design the database tables?

Comment: So without change ID name table is right do :
`SELECT * FROM USER AS u JOIN COMPANY AS c WHERE c.id=u.id `

is correct?
But i dont understand how interact variable "whaticansee" and "namecompany" for echo name and not ID

Comment: I'm not sure. I guess each ID is just the "line number" of the table. 
For me it's an SQL issue. Please, understand how works SQL joins => https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
Concataining foreign keys is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your:

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

by something slightly more complicated:

```
SELECT
   ID,
   USERNAME,
   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(NAMECOMPANY) FROM `company` AS c WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c.id, u.WHATICANSSEE)) AS WHATICANSEE
FROM `users` AS u;
```

Which should give the following result:

```
+----+----------+----------------------+
| ID | USERNAME | WHATICANSEE          |
+----+----------+----------------------+
|  1 | User     | Carrots,Apple,Potato |
+----+----------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Really thanks you, that's what i search. i will ''study'' this function.

Comment: You know why my output is cut? could it be too long?

Comment: Yes, the max length a GROUP_CONCAT can be is defined by the group_concat_max_len server system variable.This can be changed at runtime using a SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=xxx before your SELECT query.